# What happens if I no-show on a multiple person flight booking?

Tags: air-travel, tickets, legal, airlines, cancellations

Some friends and myself have booked a flight together with a budget airline (BlueAir) in a couple of days. Something has come up and I may not be able to make the flight, but my friends still intend to travel.

What happens if one individual on a multiple-person booking does not show up? I'm not concerned with getting my part of the fare back, I just want to ensure there's no effect on my friends caused by my absence, such as them being denied boarding.

I should note that this is a one-way flight, so there is no concern with being blacklisted for the return.

Comment: Telling the airline that you were not going to use the ticket a) would be helpful to the airline b) might mean that someone else who really wanted to fly on that plane would be able to buy a ticket at the last minute c) would be the nice thing to do

Comment: Sure, but with a foreign low cost airline I'm worried a miscommunication or language issue impacts the tickets of my peers.

Comment: @DJClayworth - I was in a group once where we removed one person from the booking two days before flying, and the airline accidentally *cancelled the whole 20 person booking* and didn't tell us until we turned up to check in. Luckily they were able to re-book us at last minute, but only after a lot of stress, and we only just all made the flight. I wouldn't recommend cancelling unless you are going to get a refund. (NB - the airline was Air New Guinea who are known for incompetency)

Comment: Presumably everyone is still issued individual tickets on a "multiple-person booking"?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

**Nothing happens**. Your friends fly, you forfeit your ticket.

Answer (score 11):

I have not done business with Blue Air but I have had a couple of normal bookings with multiple people and a couple of group bookings where people did not show up and absolutely nothing happens.

Most of the time when you check-in online the people at the airport will not know anything about the booking, even when you drop off your luggage.